# Rails association - Customised list of items from existing list

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a rails app where users can add tasks they wish to do to a customised list of their own. Each task can also belong to 0 or more categories. So far I've tried this:

user.rb

```
has_one :user_list
has_many :tasks, through: :user_list
```

user_list.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many   :tasks
```

tasks.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
```

[timestamp}_migration.rb

```
create_table :user_lists do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :task_id

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

The issue I am having is in the console I try to run `User.find(1).tasks` it cannot find the column `tasks.user_list_id` when using the following query:

```
SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "user_lists" ON "tasks"."user_list_id" = "user_lists"."id" WHERE "user_lists"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
```

This query should be joining the tasks id from the tasks table with the tasks id on the user_lists table. Are the associations correct and if so what can I do to change the query?

Comment: do you have `user_list_id` on tasks? why not just put `user_id` on `tasks` table, then you wouldn't need `user_tasks`

Comment: @lusketeer because a task can be added to more than one user_list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow tasks to be placed on many lists you need a M2M join table which joins the `user_lists` and `tasks` table.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_lists
  has_many :tasks, through: :user_lists
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_list_items
  has_many :user_lists, through: :user_list_items
end

class UserListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :user_list
  has_one :user, through: :user_list
  # optional
  validates_uniqueness_of :task_id, scope: :user_list_id
end

class UserList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_list_items
  has_many :tasks, through: :user_list_items
end
```

You can create the join model and migration with:

```
rails g model UserListItem user_list:belongs_to task:belongs_to
```

You may also want to open up the migration and add a compound index:

```
add_index :user_list_items, [:user_list_id, :task_id], unique: true
```

Setting it as unique is optional - but in most cases you want join table entries to be unique for table A and B.

See:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

Your use case calls for a task to be assigned to more than one user and a user has only one task list. This sounds like a HABM association between `users` and `tasks`.

The simplest way to express that would be:

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many: :tasks
  ...
end

class Task
  has_and_belongs_to_many: :users
  ...
end
```

and a migration to create the join table:

```
create_join_table :users, :tasks, do |t|
  t.index :user_id
  t.index.task_id
end
```

You don't need to create a `TaskUser` model to match the join table until you need to track additional attributes. Rails will take care of that automatically.

If a user needs more than one task list, you'll need that TaskList model. Let me know and I'll update my answer.

Here's the documentation on [HABM](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) and [join migration](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table)